# How to export Moom settings (especially keyboard shortcuts) to external file?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm working on some shell scripts to customize OS X to my preferences just by calling [one script](https://github.com/komarnicki/shell-scripts/blob/master/osx_settings.sh).

From a lot of native OS X options, script is going to easily import some predefined settings form 3rd party apps if possible.

My question is about Moom. I cannot spot any option to export existing settings (especially keyboard shortcuts) into non-encoded file.

Calling:

```
$ sudo find -x / -name "Moom"
```

gives nothing more than:

```
/Applications/Moom.app/Contents/MacOS/Moom
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Follow the instructions provided here: https://manytricks.com/osticket/kb/faq.php?id=53

In particular you have to `import` the plist, not just replace the plist with your old version.

```
defaults import com.manytricks.Moom ~/Desktop/Moom.plist
```

Comment: This works with Moom 3.2.25 on macOS Ventura in late 2022. I wonder why importing is different from drag/drop replacing.

Answer (score 2):

You can find Moom app preferences on the following file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.manytricks.Moom.plist
```

That file is not in clear text. But you can use `plutil` to convert and read it in the following way:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o - com.manytricks.Moom.plist
```

Comment: This didn't work. As well as this: https://manytricks.com/support/index.php?act=article&code=print&id=47. At least not in macOS Sierra…